# SBS 2008 - Folder Redirection

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008, folder-redirection

I have a little problem with my Folder Redirection. All seems to works fine, but when I add an element at the root of my Desktop or at the root of My Documents, it only create a temp file on the folder (and it create nothing for the elements in the sub-folders).

Ex : I created a text file in a user Desktop (test1.txt) and in the server (\testsbs\RedirectedFolders\user\Desktop) it create a temp file (frd351.tmp). And that append with all files on all user account.

Could it be a permission issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.... It was some corrupted profile on the Windows XP client machine, I just delete the profile and log-out, log-in and it works fine.

Comment: Great job getting your own answer!